# Should I use localStorage instead of cookies for web app targeted at mobile browsers?

Tags: php, javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I'm building a location-based web app that will run primarily on mobile browsers. It will be coded with HTML5, javascript, and PHP. I'd like the user to have to be prompted to login as infrequently as practical. I'd like them to login (via PHP) and then stayed logged in for x amount of time.

I know how to do this with cookies, but I've been experimenting with HTML5 localStorage. If I use localStorage, I have to do all the validation with javascript and send it to PHP via Ajax. As I'm thinking through how to get this done, I wonder if using localStorage is really worth it. From what I understand, it's more secure than cookies because the data is not transmitted with every HTTP request, and it can't be accessed cross-domain. But don't modern browsers, like iOS and Android, prevent cross-domain access to cookies?

Am I just making it harder on myself by using localStorage? What are the reasons to choose localStorage over cookies in a case like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cookies and localStorage have two different uses, mainly cookies are for reading by the server side, and localStorage is for reading by the client slide.

If your client side needs this data, then yes, use localStorage(you'll save bandwidth by not sending the cookies for every HTTP request[in the headers]). However if you are not, then just stick to using cookies. Making additional HTTP requests(via ajax) to send the server the cookies is a little overkill if all you are doing is having the server side access this data.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. The part I wasn't getting is that local storage is for data actually *used* by the client.

Comment: Thanks, that's the best explanation I've read of how these two are different.

Comment: I know this is late for the post though cookies only have a 4kb cap and localStorage has ~5mb cap, and I've tested iPhones and the storage cap on that was well over 5mb... for future references of other people visiting this.